# Show the PowerPoint presentation in web page using html

Tags: javascript, css, html

I trying to display my ppt with long time where the screen should run continuously in web page where the file is in my local folder but it is not showing in web page. The code is below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="lp.ppt" width="800px" heigt="600px" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

can anyone help to display ppt in html page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Google Docs to serve as your document viewer. You just need to upload your file and use the share link as the iframe src.

You can get the embed code by uploading your file and opening it in google docs (in this case, Google Slides) then click the file tab and click the `Publish to the Web`. From there you can copy the embed code. Make sure that the file is public! :)

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/17nlO95lz91-shRep16UiJl-3EAxv-MnOFH718ku2gtw/embed?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000" frameborder="0" width="960" height="749" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/17nlO95lz91-shRep16UiJl-3EAxv-MnOFH718ku2gtw/embed?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000" frameborder="0" width="960" height="749" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it is good. But without Google Docs, I want to display ppt in my web page from local pc because if I want make any changes from local in ppt

Comment: I think you also share the one in your local. Try this one: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Embed-a-presentation-in-a-web-page-or-blog-19668a1d-2299-4af3-91e1-ae57af723a60 :)

Comment: Yes I am using in my Local. I already try to do. But in word 2013 I cannot see the option  "Embed ". Can you say any other solution to overcome this problem. – user3301123

Comment: There is no "Embed" in word power presentation 2013, I cannot see the option "Embed ". Can you say any other solution to overcome this problem to present ppt in web page

Comment: @user3301123 the embed option is only in powerpoint online, it is the same as Google drive share, it gives you an ifram