# How can I show / preview PowerPoint presentations on my website like Box did

Tags: javascript, php, html, powerpoint, box

I have a question about PowerPoint presentations and html/php/javascript.
How can I show or preview a PowerPoint presentation on my website like the cloud website Box did ? I'm looking for more than 2 hours now and have absolutly no idea.
I hope you can help me :(
Best regards,
Philipp H.

Comment: If I tell you that PPT file format is just a zip file containing a lot of XML files describing the presentation, will that help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39246272/6647153

Comment: The problem is, I want to show the presentations from my webserver / webspace. So you can upload a presentation and see the presentation after that...

Comment: I don't think that the XML thing will help me, I don't know how to show XML from a zip containing a PPT :(