# Unable to view PPT in HTML web page using Python django

Tags: python, html, django, flash, file-upload

Currently creating an website using Python django framework using HTML and one of the features is file upload & view. It works fine with PDF documents, but when I try to view uploaded PPT documents, it always goes to download in chrome browser

Few things I tried and didn't prefer are as follows -

**1)** Using Embed PPT from Onedrive which supports already available documents.

**2)** Changing the PPT file into some other document format like PDF and viewing it directly from browser

How to view/display PPT file in HTML web page without going through above complications.

Comment: Could you share your code ?

Comment: Sorry, since the development code is confidential I won't be able to share it.

Comment: Use Google Docs to serve as your document viewer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39246453/2785080